# Python Kivy / Button - Statements are not running immeditialy?

Tags: python, kivy

i have the following example in kivy -
(enter something in the input field - and after pressing the button the label should be updated and the input field set to empty)

When i am NOT using some function after the 3 steps (read input-field, update label, set back input field) everything works fine.

But when i add some function afterwards - eg. a simple time.sleep(5) - the update is only done after running the function (after 5 seconds).

But why is this?
The time sleep function is called after updating the fields - so it is not clear for me why the fields get updated after the function call...

Maybe someone can clarify that for me...

py-file:

```
import time
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_file("14UpdateLabel.kv")

class MyLayout(Widget):
    def press(self):
        # Create variables for our widget
        name = self.ids.name_input.text

        # Update the label
        self.ids.name_label.text = name

        # Clear input box
        self.ids.name_input.text = ""

        time.sleep (5)

class AwesomeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    AwesomeApp().run()
```

kv-file:

```
<MyLayout>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

        Label:
            id: name_label
            text: "Whats Your Name"
            font_size: 32
        TextInput:
            id: name_input
            multiline: False
            size_hint: (1, .5)
        Button:
            size_hint: (1, .25)
            font_size: 32
            text: "Submit"
            on_press: root.press()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kivy's rendering is done on the main thread. The time.sleep() method is being called on the main thread, and Kivy cannot update the graphics for 5 seconds. If you use threading, you can prevent the problem.

```
import threading
class MyLayout(Widget):
    def update(self):
        # Create variables for our widget
        name = self.ids.name_input.text

        # Update the label
        self.ids.name_label.text = name

        # Clear input box
        self.ids.name_input.text = ""

        time.sleep(5)

    def press(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self.update).start()
```